# Помогите со словосочетанием

Tags: словосочетания

Помогите составить словосочетание "глагол+существительное с предлогом" 
... без кашне 
Где ... там нужно вставить глагол )
Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

"Глагол + существительное с предлогом"? Например: *гулять без кашне*.

Answer (score 0):

Ходить без кашне, обходиться без кашне, носить пальто (плащ) без кашне.